# What is a simpler way to go about reading specific lines of a text file, with varying lengths?

Tags: visual-c++

I am currently working on reading a long text file of **varying length**, with information broken down into blocks - specifically, I *attempted* to store into variables from my ifstream infile, three characters placed at various parts of the file, **with their locations written into the file itself.**

The text file I am currently reading has this structure, which I've heavily simplified:

> xxx <--- This line indicates how many lines until the NEXT line I want to read. In this case, there are 3 of the "xxx xx x" lines.
>
> a b c <--- This is the line(s) I want to read.
>
> xxx xx x
>
> xxx xx x
>
> xxx xx x
>
> xxx
>
> a b c <--- This is the line(s) I want to read.
>
> x xxx xx
>
> x xxx xx

...and so on. The file goes on for about 20 more lines with varying block lengths. As you can see the line(s) with three of the characters represented here with x's is what I'd like. The way I currently have tried to do this is with the format I was used to, that is:

```
int count = 0;
infile.get(List[count].first_item, 4);
while(infile)
{
    int temp = List[count].first_item;
    count++;
    infile.ignore(81, '\n');
    infile>> List[count].wanted_value_1;
    infile>> List[count].wanted_value_2;
    infile>> List[count].wanted_value_3;
    count++;
    infile.ignore(81, '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++)
    {
        infile.ignore(81, '\n');
        count++;
    }
    infile.get(List[count].first_item, 4);
}
```

The file read works fine for the first block, and even the second. My output when I print all this to screen looks like this:

> a b c
>
> a b c
>
> a ~and then a bunch of gibberish indicating that it points to nothing.

With my For loop, I was trying to skip the "xxx xx x" lines by however much was indicated. But I'm kind of baffled. Am I on the right track? Or is my mindset just wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I managed to figure it out! I needed to skip another line after my For loop. It works like a charm now.